# can not display quantity_and_stock_status attribute in layered navigation in magento 2

Tags: filter, magento2, stock

I have tried to set quantity_and_stock_status attribute to make filterable on the product list page. I have set it from the admin panel(Stores -> Attributes -> Product) but I can not see a stock filter on the front end. What could be the issue? Please provide a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> quantity_and_stock_status

is the attribute code name is

> Quantity

When changing the settings I have found a bug,it didn't save and showed the loading image,

It was a magento 2 bug same as https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8202 ,

> for a quick solution you can do is inspect the options and remove the
>   disabled attribute and then save.

It worked for me.